# SpringSecurity: Obtengo bad credencials en el método return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

estoy obteniendo un error cuando intento crear la autenticación de un usuario, he podido descubrir que el error se produce porque no está cargado ese usuario en memoria y esto es un problema, ya que los usuarios deben salir de la base de datos, pero no voy a volcar a todos los usuarios en memoria....

El tutorial lo saqué de aquí:
https://windoctor7.github.io/spring-jwt.html

El código es el siguiente:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es.....service")
public class ServiciosConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LoginFilter createLogin() throws Exception {
        return new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() //permitimos el acceso a /login a cualquiera
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
            .and()
            // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
           .addFilterBefore(createLogin(),  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // Las demás peticiones pasarán por este filtro para validar el token
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Creamos una cuenta de usuario por default
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("edu")
                .password("123")
                .roles("ADMIN");
    }
```

Aquí se hacen 3 cosas:

Se capturan las peticiones y si es login, se comprueba el usuario en    BD, si es correcto crea el token.  (Este es el problema)

Sino es login, comprueba el token. (Esto funciona)

Guarda usuarios en memoria (Este es el problema)

```
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private RolesUserRepository rolRepository;

    public LoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        // obtenemos el body de la peticion que asumimos viene en formato JSON
        InputStream body = req.getInputStream();

        // Realizamos un mapeo a nuestra clase User para tener ahi los datos
        User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, User.class);

        // Finalmente autenticamos
        LOGGER.info("Buscando al usuario: " + user.getUser() + " en la BD.");
        RolesUser rol = this.rolRepository.findByUser(user.getUser());

        if (rol.getRol() != null) {
            LOGGER.info("El usuario: " + user.getUser() + " es correcto.");

            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(rol.getRol());
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUser(),
                    user.getPwd(), grantedAuths));
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Credenciales inválidas.") {
            };
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Si la autenticacion fue exitosa, agregamos el token a la respuesta
        JwtUtil.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}

class User {
    private String user;
    private String pwd;

    public User() {}

    public User(String user, String pwd) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }
    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, para autenticar al usuario lo busco en la base de datos, si es correcto hago un

return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUser(),
                    user.getPwd(), grantedAuths));

Y ahora el problema:
Si el usuario existe en la BD pero no está en el @Override

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Creamos una cuenta de usuario por default
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("edu")
            .password("123")
            .roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Revienta en la línea del return getAuthenticationManager....Obtengo un error de la clase `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` de org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Pero si está en esa línea, funciona perfectamente, el problema es que no puedo tener a los usuarios cargados en memoria, de tal modo que necesito poder "quitar del código el `auth.inMemoryAuthentication()` y que funcione, yo "creo" que quizás deba de ser por la clase usada `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`  pero es la que siempre encuentro en las págs webs. 
Gracias!

---

*-------------------------------------------------*

Después de algunas modificaciones el código se queda así: Pero sigue fallando:

En el WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es....service")
public class ServiciosConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Bean
    public LoginFilter createLogin() throws Exception {
        return new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll() // permitimos el acceso a /login a
                                                                                    // cualquiera
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
                .and()
                // Las peticiones /login pasaran previamente por este filtro
                .addFilterBefore(createLogin(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // Las demás peticiones pasarán por este filtro para validar el token
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

En el WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, hago un "PassEncoder" y quito el guardado en memoria que es lo que no quiero tener, porque quiero sacar a los usuarios de la base de datos, así que en su lugar creo una implementación nueva:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired 
    private RolesUserRepository repository;

    public void UserService(RolesUserRepository repository) {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        RolesUser rolUser = repository.findByUser(userName);
        if(rolUser.getRol() != null) {
          LOGGER.info("El usuario: " + userName + " es: " + rolUser.getRol());
          List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(rolUser.getRol());
          return new MyUserPrincipal(grantedAuths,"$2a$10$slYQmyNdGzTn7ZLBXBChFOC9f6kFjAqPhccnP6DxlWXx2lPk1C3G6",userName);
        }else {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Las credenciales son incorrectas.") {
            };
        }
    }
```

Esta es la nueva implementación, se comprueba si existe ese usuario en la base de datos (da igual su contraseña) y si tiene rol es que existe y creo la clase userDetail para que pueda ser validada.

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths;
private String password;
private String userName;

public MyUserPrincipal(List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths, String password, String userName) {
    this.grantedAuths = grantedAuths;
    this.password = password;
    this.userName = userName;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.grantedAuths;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.userName;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

}

Aquí tuve que cambiar los return a true porque me estaban dando diferentes errores.

Finalmente, en la clase donde antaño tenía la comprobación, ahora se queda vacía:
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

```
    public LoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        // obtenemos el body de la peticion que asumimos viene en formato JSON
        InputStream body = req.getInputStream();

        // Realizamos un mapeo a nuestra clase User para tener ahi los datos
        User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, User.class);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            user.getUser(),
                            user.getPwd(),
                            Collections.emptyList()
                    )
            );

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Si la autenticacion fue exitosa, agregamos el token a la respuesta
        JwtUtil.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}

class User {
    private String user;
    private String pwd;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String user, String pwd) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

}
```

Me he estado guiando para esta parte de:
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt-mysql

El error que obtengo es el mismo que antes "BAD CREDENTIALS" en la clase

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider, Línea 171.
        catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
            if (cacheWasUsed) {
                // There was a problem, so try again after checking
                // we're using latest data (i.e. not from the cache)
                cacheWasUsed = false;
                user = retrieveUser(username,
                        (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
                preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
                additionalAuthenticationChecks(user,
                        (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
            }
```

En la depuración, la variable de authentication tiene lo siguiente:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ffce9fa1: Principal: jose; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leyendo tu post me doy cuenta que lo que necesitas es poder ir a buscar en la bd el user logeado, ya que no quieres que esté en memoria, por lo tanto lo que se me ocurre es que cambies en el metodo **configure**

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Creamos una cuenta de usuario por default
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("edu")
            .password("123")
            .roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Se cambia por

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(loginFilter) 
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Tendrás que crear el bean para el pwd enconder.

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Luego se deberá de cambiar la clase LoginFilter para que  que implemente 
**org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService**
Esto ya implica un refactor para que la autenticación quede del lado de la clase **ServiciosConfig**  si quieres Guíarte de un ejemplo puedes ir a: [https://github.com/OmarHHM/rest/]
Saludo, espero te funcione.

Comment: buenas Omar, justamente estaba probando esto: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt-mysql, tal y como indicas estaba usando el UserDetailsService y el userDetails pero sigo con el mismo problema de bad credentials, ahora me tengo que ir pero mañana modifico todo el post a ver si se soluciona esto de una vez, muchas gracias!

Comment: ya está modificado el post, básicamente tengo todo eso, el passEncoder, el userDetailService y demás, pero me da error de "Bad credentials", te suena de qué podría ser ??

Comment: Prueba cambiando el tipo de encriptado,                                                   
        @Bean
 public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 }